# Отправка готового файла SOAP запроса

Tags: xml, wsdl, php, soap

Приветствую.
Имеется ряд файлов `*.soap`, с готовыми `XML` запросами. Их нужно отправить удалённому сервису и зафиксировать ответы.
Вопрос: как их отправить? В классе `SOAPClient` вроде нет функций для готовых файлов, а расписывать код для каждого удалённого метода с нуля во-первых, долго, во-вторых, придётся пересмотреть все эти файлы. Зачем всё это, если запросы уже написаны и нужно только отправить.
Может быть есть какой-то класс или метод для таких задач?

Comment: [Click](https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+soapclient&oq=php+soap&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l4.5577j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&newwindow=1&q=soapclient%20send%20raw%20xml)  
[Click 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009554/php-soapclient-send-custom-xml)